# How to create bilateral relationship between classes with generics involved

Tags: java, generics

I have and abstract class `Image` which has two implementations: `CTImage` and `CRImage`. Specific type of Image is a part of Series (also abstract) with two implementations: `CTSeries` and `CRSeries`. When the object of specific Image is created it should create proper Series object, and add itself to proper implementation of `Series` .

Code I produced does not compile. Line `this.series.addImage(this); produces:

```
Required type:
capture of ? extends Image<S>

Provided:
Image<S>
```

The workaround is to add image to series in every implementation (commented lines) but that makes me reapeat myself. I just can't figure out what's the problem and how to fix it.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

abstract class Series<T extends Image<?>> {
    protected List<T> images = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addImage(T img) {
        this.images.add(img);
    }

    public List<T> getImages() {
        return images;
    }
}

class CTSeries extends Series<CTImage> {
}

class CRSeries extends Series<CRImage> {
}

abstract class Image<S extends Series<? extends Image<S>>> {
    protected S series;

    public Image() {
        this.series = createSeries();
        this.series.addImage(this);
    }

    public S getSeries() {
        return series;
    }

    protected abstract S createSeries();

}

class CTImage extends Image<CTSeries> {

    public CTImage() {
//        series.addImage(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected CTSeries createSeries() {
        return new CTSeries();
    }
}

class CRImage extends Image<CRSeries> {

    public CRImage() {
//        series.addImage(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected CRSeries createSeries() {
        return new CRSeries();
    }
}
```

Comment: The relationship is weird. What's the point of an image adding itself to its series?

Comment: @Sweeper In some parts of my app I have reference to image only and need to know which Series it is a part of. I can't see why this relationship is weird. When student attends school both sides have the knowledge about each other.

Comment: But a student wouldn't create a school just to put themselves in there...

Comment: What I expected was rather technical discussion, not the business side of my app.

Comment: We're asking because there isn't a great, smooth solution to this and redesigning this arrangement may be the best strategy.

Comment: Technically there is no problem with the design. It's just that Java's generics is not expressive enough to do this. Specifically, it has no self-types. Even [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) can't help in this case.

Comment: Would a Factory + Observer pattern help in this case as the requirement is to Add to the list upon creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done, but the types get a little complex, and there is still a small amount of necessary duplication.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

abstract class Series<S extends Series<S, I>, I extends Image<I, S>> {
    protected List<I> images = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addImage(I img) {
        this.images.add(img);
    }

    public List<I> getImages() {
        return images;
    }
}

class CTSeries extends Series<CTSeries, CTImage> {
}

class CRSeries extends Series<CRSeries, CRImage> {
}

abstract class Image<I extends Image<I, S>, S extends Series<S, I>> {
    protected S series;

    public Image() {
        this.series = createSeries();
        this.series.addImage(thisImage());
    }

    protected abstract I thisImage();

    public S getSeries() {
        return series;
    }

    protected abstract S createSeries();

}

class CTImage extends Image<CTImage, CTSeries> {

    public CTImage() {
    }

    @Override
    public CTImage thisImage() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    protected CTSeries createSeries() {
        return new CTSeries();
    }
}

class CRImage extends Image<CRImage, CRSeries> {

    public CRImage() {
    }

    @Override
    public CRImage thisImage() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    protected CRSeries createSeries() {
        return new CRSeries();
    }
}
```

Other than the self-referential type parameters, the major change is the addition of the abstract `thisImage` method, which is used instead of `this` in the call to `this.series.addImage`. This is because there is no way in Java to express "the type of this object". The concrete implementations all need to implement this method as `return this;`. There's no way for it to be inherited from the `Image` base class, as the compiler can't enforce that all possible subclasses will specify their own type as the value of `I`.